How to implement image textures into cell shading
I'm currently working on a personal project and ran into a small technical hiccup. 
I wanted to try my hand at making an anime-style model using hand-drawn shadows combined with normally edited anime shading. The idea was that I'd draw areas on the model where the shadows should ALWAYS be, such as between the eye and brows, under the nose and lips, and the eye shade. Then, I'd add a basic anime shader and make it so that the shadow color would be the same as the hand-drawn shadow color, creating a seamless effect between what's hand-drawn and what's calculated by blender. It's similar to what I think epic games used for their Omni-Man model.

Turns out it's not that simple. It's weird because making the factor 1/2 doesn't give the colors the seamless transition I wanted. I honestly thought that'd work. I swear I've seen people do what I'm trying to do online, but I haven't found a signle straight forward video that shows how to implement image textures into a shader the way I'm trying to.
Am I going crazy here?
If what I'm trying to do is fundamentally impossible, or there's a better way to do it, please let me know.
Link to file: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/ckkufrx4nknxo/Detective+Grey
Let me know if you have any problems with the link.
Thanks!

You can simplify the 2 last nodes by simply using a Mix Color node. What you have is 2 colors, no need to go through a Mix Shader (although I don't think it changes the result). In both cases, mix set to 0.5 means you want one color to be 50% transparent and put over the other color, you can see it this way. I think you'd rather play with a black&white range (instead of dark skintone and light skintone) and use a Mix node set to Multiply. Only then you want to go from black&white to skin colors. More flexibility and it simplifies the masking part. I'll try to write a full answer soon.

Single-color light and textured cel-shading
There are multiple ways of achieving cel-shading with Eevee. There is no one-way to do it, each one has its pros and cons. I'll explain a simple one that offers nice flexibility.
Limitation

Only one color of light and one color of shadow is possible. You can't have a red light and a green light at the same time.

Advantage

Flexibility : lighting is done in shader, tint and brightness of light parts, and tint and brightness of shadow parts

Method
First, I am starting with 2 textures. The first one is the base colored texture, the second one is the shadow map :

More grayscale values on the shadow map can be possible.
Then, what you want to do is to get the same range of value as the shadow map with your shader

Now, mixing the 2 black&white textures is simply a matter of multiplying the textures. Remember that black is 0, so any black part will stay black after the multiplication even if the other texture has white.

After that, we can finally choose our lighting. You could tint your shadows, tint your highlights, or don't give any color and just set the brightness. Finally, we Multiply the shadow map with the colored texture to get the final result

Here are the nodes. You'll note that the setup is quite similar to yours

By tweaking the Color Ramp which controls the lighting, you can get any lighting you want.


I tried following the steps, but it didn't seem to work out for me. I made a version of my texture where his whole face was covered in shadow, safe for the eyes and eyelid folds. I plugged the image into the shadow map node. It seemed just to make my model darker. There wasn't any change when I rotated the light source or sun in this case. The only thing affected was the eye whites. Am I missing something? I would put an image down, but it's not letting me.
